# How to gradually convert a site over to CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've been doing a lot of research in regards to OO and MVC for PHP and have nearly made a choice to move to CodeIgniter for an existing large-scale website I manage. I feel that using an OO+MVC environment has a huge organizational and performance advantages and hopefully improved developing speed compared to the existing functional/procedural structure the site uses now.

However, due to the sheer size of the site, I would like to gradually transfer the code over to CodeIgniter's structure thus having a transitional time period where parts of the site are in CI and others are in the old style.

Are there any suggestions on the best way to do this from a code structure point of view while minimizing on the amount of duplicate code? I'm rather new to OO as well, and feel that gradual is the best way to do this due to the learning curve.

Comment: It is hard to say where to begin or what the advancement should be. Though it is a good question, it is very broad to answer it... Anyway should I do such a task I would definitely start over with re/writting models, controllers and views that will use that models, forms until everything is working at least within frontend - on a local machine. The next step will be to rewrite the backend part should there be any. After all done and working I would publish it finally.

Comment: to really help need more details - what does your website do? will the database and PHP version remain the same? what improvements are you looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could install CI into a folder and redirect (though `.htaccess`) only the requests that you want to handle with CI. Other than that, everything should work as usual and you won't need to change much of your current functionality. The more sections work on CI, the more redirect rules you will have.

Comment: I'd agree with this approach. If you go with re-writing the site from scratch, then you'll have to put new developments on hold until the rewrite is finished. Analyse the app in terms of sections, and see what you can rewrite/integrate first. I've not used CI, but I would imagine that you don't need to use its models system initially - get stuff working in actions and views, and then move to a model-based approach once it is live and bedded in.

Comment: While the other suggestions are really good ones, I think this is the best for a gradual transfer over. As @halfer has mentioned, it allows developments to continue while transferring the site over which is extremely important in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to determine the dependent entities in your database (models) and start with them first such as some contacts, users registration and so on.

The most reliable and safe way, you have to copy your current working site to a local machine and start do it bit by bit, till you finish it all, upload it to your public web server.

Answer (score 0):

I would just write the entire site (almost) from scratch, locally, then when everything's working and tested upload it to the server.

By 'almost' from scratch I mean you could copy some of the HTML into View files, and perhaps use some of the existing PHP for piecing together parts of the backend, but I think you'll have to write most of it from the start. I made a semi-large scale web in object oriented way using the MVC pattern, and even transfering that to CodeIgniter wouldn't be a trivial task, much less a website that's written completely procedurally. That is my opinion.